# Raman spectra in Gaussian

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software, raman

I want to simulate Raman spectra of benzene in Gaussian 09.

Calculated spectra for a single ring Benzene ($\ce{C6H6}$) in Gaussian differs about $\pu{40 cm^{-1}}$ for each peak, compared with experimental Raman's databases.

How can I solve this problem?
Gaussian file created with GaussView6:
MP2 config
[image]

DFT config:
[image]

Parameters: (for optimization)
[image]

Comment: When discussion computational chemistry (and particularly when asking for advice), it's important to say which method(s) and basis sets you are using. Gaussian 09 is a software package with many very different quantum chemistry methods.

Comment: Did you scale it? Did you compare it to gas phase data?

Comment: @Persian_Gulf PJR is correct. The methods and basis set used are crucial for understanding what wrong with your results. If you could include your input script, that would be helpful in answering the questions.

Comment: @PJR I tried DFT and MP2. But it still is differs from experimental results. (MP2 is a little better).

Comment: @DSVA In Gaussview, I entered a single Benzene molecule. Is it possible to consider liquid phase in calculation?

Comment: For the DFT please also specify the functional (e.g. b3lyp ) since that also makes a huge difference. As @Tyberius said, the input script would really be the most helpful. The basis set you are using will also make a difference and the default is not necessarily suitable. In general, I would recommend increasing the basis set to something of at least triple zeta quality (potentially quadruple since benzene is so small). You also have the option of using an ab-initio method like CCSD or CCSD(T) but those will take considerably longer.

Comment: @PJR I added the config files made by GaussView

Comment: Liquid phase is possible at least as implicit solvent models via the scrf keyword.

Comment: +1. Sorry to see your question was closed. I'm trying to create a Stack Exchange just for computational chemistry and materials modeling, and questions like this would be very welcome. Do you think you can help support us by clicking commit?
https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGFkOGRlMTg1ODg2NTUxZDQ1MDVjZmQyOTg1ZDcxODQzMjc0OGIyMjBhZDM4ZDQ5MzM0MWE1YzZhNDBjMzhlYfHJBfp5EvPDPybryqjeDgXYucHU-wUv4jp4j6imjIfF0 Only 2.7% of committers fulfill commitment anyway, but it would be very very helpful if you could support us.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for attaching your input file.
The first place to start for improving these calculations is your choice of basis set. 6-31G is a rather small basis set and is likely a source of significant error here. If you're fond of using the Pople type basis then you would be better off using something like 6-31++G* so that you include polarization and diffuse functions. With your current basis I suspect that you are missing important polarization of the atoms upon distortion.

If you really wanted a very accurate answer I would recommend the following scheme. Optimize your geometry at the DFT level and then use that geometry as a starting place for a optimization and frequency calculation at a higher level of theory. For example use the cc-pvtz basis set (a correlation consistent basis set that's more efficient generally than the Pople type) and CCSD(T). This will provide a very accurate gas phase raman spectrum.

Edit:
The only additional Gaussian specific parameter you should need is the Geom=Checkpoint command for the CCSD(T) optimization and frequency run. This will use your existing checkpoint file as a geometry starting point. 
The other keywords (basis and method) are exactly what they should be cc-pvdz and ccsd(t). For more information on basis keywords I recommend the users manual.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You mean I set the optimization (DFT/ccpvtz) and for frequency CCSD. may I ask you to  specify all parameters?

Comment: I added the parameter for optimization below my question.